# Populate list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of type `RawResults` where `RawResults` is a location and a date

```
public class RawResult
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDate {get; set; }

    public RawResults(string l, DateTime d)
    {
        this.location = l;
        this.createDate = d;
    }
}
```

I would like to use LINQ to populate a list containing each distinct location and the number of times it appears in my arraylist.  If I able to do it in SQL it would look like this

```
select 
   bw.location, 
   count(*) as Count
from 
   bandwidth bw, 
   media_log ml
where
   bw.IP_SUBNET = ml.SUBNET
   group by bw.location
   order by location asc
```

later I will also have to do the same thing, but within a given date range.

UPDATE
this is the query that was run to get all of the data in `rawData`

```
SELECT        
    MEDIASTREAM.BANDWIDTH.LOCATION, MEDIASTREAM.MEDIA_LOG.CREATE_DATE
FROM            
    MEDIASTREAM.BANDWIDTH INNER JOIN
      MEDIASTREAM.MEDIA_LOG ON MEDIASTREAM.BANDWIDTH.IP_SUBNET =     
      MEDIASTREAM.MEDIA_LOG.SUBNET
```

Now I need to query the data that was returned in `rawData` to get different result sets.  I have available a List to query.

Comment: Before anything: use a `List<RawResult>`.

Comment: thanks, I changed type back to `List<RawResult>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var results = 
    (from bw in data.bandwith
     join ml in data.media_log on bw.IP_SUBNET equals ml.SUBNET
     group bw by bw.location into g
     orderby g.Key
     select new 
     { 
         location = g.Key, 
         Count = g.Count() 
     })
    .ToList();
```

Although the `ToList` is not necessary unless you absolutely *need* it to be a `List<T>`. To filter by time, you can just do something like this:

```
var results = 
    (from bw in data.bandwith
     join ml in data.media_log on bw.IP_SUBNET equals ml.SUBNET
     where bw.createDate >= minDate && bw.createDate <= maxDate
     group bw by bw.location into g
     orderby g.Key
     select new 
     { 
         location = g.Key, 
         Count = g.Count() 
     })
    .ToList();
```

---

If `media_log` isn't relevant, you can just omit the `join`:

```
var results = 
    from bw in data.bandwith
    group bw by bw.location into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new 
    { 
        location = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count() 
    }
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = data.bandwith
    .GroupBy(bw => bw.location, (k, g) => new { location = k, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderBy(r => r.location);
```

To filter by date, just use this:

```
var results = 
    from bw in data.bandwith
    where bw.createDate >= minDate && bw.createDate <= maxDate
    group bw by bw.location into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new 
    { 
        location = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count() 
    };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = data.bandwith
    .Where(bw => bw.createDate >= minDate && bw.createDate <= maxDate)
    .GroupBy(bw => bw.location, (k, g) => new { location = k, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderBy(r => r.location);
```

Note, to use an `ArrayList`, or any other non-generic collection type in a Linq query, use the [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) or [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) methods, like this:

```
var results = bandwithArrayList
    .Cast<RawResults>()
    .GroupBy(bw => bw.location, (k, g) => new { location = k, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I only have `ArrayList<RawResults> rawData` to run the LINQ on.

Comment: @Mike Your question referenced `media_log`, so I assumed that was important. If it's not relevant at all, you can just leave it out of the query. See my updated answer.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Good point, I've included a note about how to use `ArrayList`'s in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry to be confusing. I will update my question to include more information.

Comment: @Mike Okay. My second solution, or [*EkoostikMartin*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17176674/1715579)'s should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<RawResult> results = MethodToGetResults();

var locationCount = results
     .GroupBy(r => r.location)
     .Select(lc => new {Location = lc.location, Count = lc.Count()});
```